# Speed up getting Firebase Values in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a Player and an Enemy in a scene and when one player moves, it updates the Firebase with its position perfectly, fast and exact. But when updating the enemy for the other player, it takes a long time.
                                                                             **Code for Enemy Updater:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;

public class enemyUpdater : MonoBehaviour {

private DatabaseReference dataBase;
private bool gameStarted = false;
private float Z;
private float X;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    // Set up the Editor before calling into the realtime database.
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("Not Showing This");

    // Get the root reference location of the database.
    dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    setup();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    this.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(X, this.gameObject.transform.position.y, Z);
}

void HandleU1XChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    string tmp = args.Snapshot.Value.ToString();
    float.TryParse(tmp, out X);
}

void HandleU1ZChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    string tmp = args.Snapshot.Value.ToString();
    float.TryParse(tmp, out Z);
}

void HandleU2XChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    string tmp = args.Snapshot.Value.ToString();
    float.TryParse(tmp, out X);
}

void HandleU2ZChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    string tmp = args.Snapshot.Value.ToString();
    float.TryParse(tmp, out Z);
}

void setup()
{
    if (multiSetup.isUserOne)
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(7.5f, this.gameObject.transform.position.y, -7.5f);
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference("matches").Child("rooms").Child("room"+multiSetup.roomNum).Child("user2").Child("Xaxis")
            .ValueChanged += HandleU1XChanged;
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference("matches").Child("rooms").Child("room" + multiSetup.roomNum).Child("user2").Child("Zaxis")
            .ValueChanged += HandleU1ZChanged;
    }
    else if (!multiSetup.isUserOne)
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(-7.5f, this.gameObject.transform.position.y, 7.5f);
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference("matches").Child("rooms").Child("room" + multiSetup.roomNum).Child("user1").Child("Xaxis")
            .ValueChanged += HandleU1XChanged;
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference("matches").Child("rooms").Child("room" + multiSetup.roomNum).Child("user1").Child("Zaxis")
            .ValueChanged += HandleU1ZChanged;
    }
}
}
```

**Here's a GIF of it in Action**
As well as the delayed updating
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tv4BCfVsV6AIjEiKE1Umj4FfIyy-AG-R

Answer (score 0):

The reason the local client updates immediately is because the Firebase client fires the events for local write operations straight away.

The time for the change to make it from one player to the other is a combination of their respective latencies to the Firebase servers and the bandwidth required to send and receive the change. There is no magic "make it faster" setting or code to reduce that time, it's simply the reality of sending data via a cloud service.

The trick the Firebase client does locally is one way to hide the reality of the network. Various games deal with this reality in various ways. Some predict the enemy's future behavior based on what they've recently done, some show the enemy's past behavior as a ghost, some incorporate the delay into their gameplay mechanics, etc.